# I made some changes in the database tables. I baked my model again but the changes are not reflecting in the app

Tags: cakephp

What you CakePHP guys do when you do some changes in database table. I added a field in the table after I baked the entire application, and baked again that model. But didn't do anything in the controller.

Comment: There shouldn't be any modifications to make in the Controller if you're adding a table field. In your model you might want to have a validation for that field. It's unnecessary to bake again. To Display the Field just edit your views and add it where you want it (e.g. form, index-table, ...)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways for the reflected changes of database into our application:

1. Delete all the temporary model files from `app/tmp/cache/models/*`.
2. Change the debug value from `2` to `0` and again change it from `0` to `2` in `app/Config/core.php`

This technique always worked for me.

Comment: Of these, changing the debug value to 2 is not recommended on production servers, as it will expose detailed errors, SQL queries etc.